# Why doesn't XUL load handler work?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xul, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox dev tools, it seems the XUL iframes won't fire after the initial onload. For example, see the [bottom of this file](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/blob/master/content/inspectorTweaks.js#L172), where the extension makes the selected element in the inspector more easy to see. This is working when you open the inspector, but when you click to another page it reverts to the old inspector tree style. I even tried `frame.contentWindow.addEventListener('load',styleit);`, but it doesn't fire when a link is clicked on the web page, and page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) get a reference of the InspectorPanel object
b) listen for the `ready` event

```js
var ip = window.ownerDocument.defaultView.inspector;`
ip.on("ready", styleit)
```

Comment: Close. `window.inspector.on("markuploaded", styleit);` works on page switch. I found that in the `inspector-panel.js`. Do you know if there's any documentation on the .emit and .on that is used in dev tools?